# How to stop vagrant from freezing during disk usage

Tags: vagrant, debian, composer-php, virtualbox

My vagrant machine keeps freezing under moderate disk usage, such as running `composer install` (freezes during extraction) or running scripts which write to log files often.  When it freezes, it will not respond to `ctl-C`, but I can `vagrant ssh` into a new terminal window.  When I do this and inspect disk space and memory, nothing appears to be maxed out.

I've tried running `vagrant box update`, updating vagrant itself, and increasing allocated memory.  I've also destroyed and rebuilt the VM, but to no avail.

Any suggestions to make this work?

I'm running debian/contrib-jessie64 v8.6.2, Vagrant 1.8.6 using VirtualBox.
My Vagrantfile includes the following:

```
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--cpus', '1']
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--memory', 1024]
    vb.customize(["modifyvm", :id, "--rtcuseutc", "on"])
    vb.customize(["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"])
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--vram', 128]
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--ioapic', 'on']
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--chipset', 'ich9']
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--pae', 'on']
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nictype1', 'virtio']
    vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--nictype2', 'virtio']
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, I fixed my problem by changing the `synced_folder` type from nfs to default in my `Vagrantfile`:

Original:

`config.vm.synced_folder "/path/to/local/folder", "/path/to/guest/folder", type: "nfs" , :mount_options => ['rw', 'vers=3', 'udp', 'actimeo=1']`

Updated:

`config.vm.synced_folder "/path/to/local/folder", "/path/to/guest/folder"`

As this is working for my situation, I didn't go into detail comparing synced folder types or tuning them, but more information about NFS performance can be found here:
https://www.inovex.de/blog/doh-my-vagrant-nfs-is-slow/